# unable to logon to moodle server from other machine on network

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am new to moodle installation and configuration.
Recently I downloaded moodle and installed it on Cent OS 6
I am able to log on in Moodle from server machine.
My doubt here is what configurations need to be carried out so as Moodle can be accessed over network.
I made one change in config.php file
I updated value of **$CFG->wwwroot** as

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://192.168.0.10/moodle';
```

where 192.168.0.10 is IP of Server machine where moodle is installed.
Still I am unable to acess moodle from other machine..
Help in this regard is appreciated..

Comment: Are you sure it is the same network and that the server machine is open to be viewed by others in the network?

Comment: Yes, Its is Computer LAB where I am trying to configure moodle server?

Comment: Can you ping the server from another machine? Can you reach Apache (the web server) from another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that other system is connected on network, You did it correctly but I think it is network issue due to that you are not able to access it on other system.